# Overfull \hbox warning in tabular

Tags: tables, tabularx, warnings

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{cc*{2}{S[table-format=-1.3]}
                       S[table-format= 1.3]
                       S
                       S[table-format=-1.3]
                       S[table-format= 3.3]
                       S[table-format= 1.3]}
\toprule
& {\stackon{}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}} 
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[px]}{\textbf{RMS}\vphantom{y}}} \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{P\textit{n}P-LM}}
    & A & 2.748  & -0.135 & 2.175 & 119.232 & 1.368  & -76.261 & 0.240\\ 
    & B & 2.690  & 0.768  & 2.128 & 124.905 & -1.972 & -91.559 & 0.247\\
    & C & -1.576 & 1.139  & 2.146 & 120.264 & 1.428  & 98.205  & 0.255\\
    & D & -1.575 & -0.122 & 2.165 & 119.634 & -0.818 & 85.313  & 0.231\\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{EP\textit{n}P}}
    & A & 2.722  & -0.161 & 2.345 & 121.639 & 1.828  & -75.974 & 0.463\\
    & B & 2.649  & 0.729  & 2.259 & 127.082 & -0.881 & -91.444 & 0.432\\
    & C & -1.565 & 1.148  & 2.246 & 121.639 & 1.250  & 98.377  & 0.389\\
    & D & -1.547 & -0.077 & 2.238 & 120.951 & 0.199  & 85.428  & 0.372\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\caption{Exterior orientation parameters and corresponding RMS error for all Kinect sensors defined within the chessboard coordinate system.}
\label{tab:rigidParams}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Although it is placed within the width of the text it gives me an  overfull warning. I would like to understand why.

Comment: This does not compile.  Changing from standalone to article fixes the compilation issue, but as you say, there are overfull boxes.

Comment: I have no idea what the root cause is, since I have no clue what magic is conjured by the packages you're using.  But the following fixes the issue, with a barely noticeable change in appearance (to me): change the tabular spec to all {lll lll lll}

Comment: @Mark How do you mean change the tabular spec? Can you propose another way of writing this table so it looks the same?

Comment: Almost the same.  after \begin{tabular}, and before \toprule, you have a bunch of stuff.  Try replacing it by a bunch of `l`s.  Like 9 `l`s.  Or maybe `c`s if you think that looks better.

Answer (score 2):

The overfull boxes come from the minus signs in the penultimate column. I detected this by adding `\showoutput` to the original file (with `article` class rather than `standalone`, as the latter gave a compilation error).  You have just missed the minus in your format specification for the column; it should be

```
 S[table-format=-3.3]
```

rather than `S[table-format= 3.3]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{cc*{2}{S[table-format=-1.3]}
                       S[table-format= 1.3]
                       S
                       S[table-format=-1.3]
                       S[table-format=-3.3]
                       S[table-format=1.3]}
\toprule
& {\stackon{}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}} 
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[px]}{\textbf{RMS}\vphantom{y}}} \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{P\textit{n}P-LM}}
    & A & 2.748  & -0.135 & 2.175 & 119.232 & 1.368  & -76.261 & 0.240\\ 
    & B & 2.690  & 0.768  & 2.128 & 124.905 & -1.972 & -91.559 & 0.247\\
    & C & -1.576 & 1.139  & 2.146 & 120.264 & 1.428  & 98.205  & 0.255\\
    & D & -1.575 & -0.122 & 2.165 & 119.634 & -0.818 & 85.313  & 0.231\\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{EP\textit{n}P}}
    & A & 2.722  & -0.161 & 2.345 & 121.639 & 1.828  & -75.974 & 0.463\\
    & B & 2.649  & 0.729  & 2.259 & 127.082 & -0.881 & -91.444 & 0.432\\
    & C & -1.565 & 1.148  & 2.246 & 121.639 & 1.250  & 98.377  & 0.389\\
    & D & -1.547 & -0.077 & 2.238 & 120.951 & 0.199  & 85.428  & 0.372\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\caption{Exterior orientation parameters and corresponding RMS error for all Kinect sensors defined within the chessboard coordinate system.}
\label{tab:rigidParams}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```